# Is 'I'm' a verb, noun, adjective, or adverb?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, adverbs, nouns

I am currently doing my online work, and I was sorting verbs, nouns, adjectives and adverbs. I was doing well, until '**I'm**' came up. I would *really* appreciate it if someone could answer my question, is '**I'm**' a verb, noun, adjective, of adverb? I am thinking it might be a noun, but I am unsure.

Comment: **I'm** is a contraction of **I** and **am**; 'I' is a pronoun and 'am' is a verb.

Comment: I need adverb, verb, adjective or noun. Which one is it out of those 4?

Comment: The correct answer is it's none of them, it's a contraction of two words, one a pronoun, the other a verb.  That said, if forced to choose, I'd say it's a verb.  (In some languages, and in some forms of informal English, "am" on its own can replace "I'm".)

Comment: However, because the only correct answer is "none of the above", I have no way of knowing what your teacher had in mind or what the person who set the exercise intended - unless it was that "I'm" should be skipped over.

Comment: @rjpond Ok thanks. The only one that answered my question :)

Comment: @rjpond yo do you know how to follow someone's profile? I want to follow yours, cause you are being helpful

Comment: @DragonairGirl I don't think that feature exists ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57334/is-there-a-way-to-follow-a-user-on-stack-overflow ) - you can bookmark the user's page, or try the StackEye Chrome extension (I haven't tested this) ( https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackeye/pihfndpmcafdecheofkjfkadecoogigm ).  Whilst I'm glad I could help, please remain polite when responding to other commenters, as they are just trying to help, too! Thanks.

Comment: @rjpond Oh my god you were right XD Its a verb :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/rjpond isn't working for me so... :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118982/discussion-between-dragonair-girl-and-rjpond).

Answer (score 1):

**I'm** is a *contraction*.  It is a contraction of the words "I" and "am".  Because it is a contraction, it is not a noun, verb, or an adjective.

"I" is a proper noun, and "am" is a verb.

Comment: We need either noun, verb, adjective, or adverb :/

Comment: Whatever your exercise says, this is the correct information about _I'm_.

Comment: @KateBunting I know that I'm is a contraction, I have not been given the answer yet, I need one of these fricking options: noun, verb, adjective, or adverb. WHAT DO YOU PEOPLE NOT UNDERSTAND ABOUT THAT

Comment: We understand perfectly well, but the correct answer is **not** one of those options! Unless they just want you to say that _am_ is a verb. Being rude helps nobody.

Comment: @KateBunting Well, you are incorrect. It is in fact a verb. I got the answer recently. A verb is a doing **or being word** and I'm is a being word. Also sorry :/ I was just mad because no one was answering my question.

Comment: As several people have told you, _I'm_ is a pronoun _and_ a verb.